# The textFieldShouldReturn is not working to change focus from one textfield to another in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I made everything to apply change focus from one `textField` to another when clicking on the next button from keyboard in IOS but it's not working .

I make the delegate for each `textField` to `ViewController` from layout and from code. 
[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    usernameTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self

}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textfield: UITextField!) -> Bool
{

    textfield.resignFirstResponder()

    if (textfield == self.usernameTextField) {
        self.usernameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    }
    else if (textfield == self.passwordTextField) {
        self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    }

    return true


}
```

What it is the wrong in this case ?

Comment: is it textFieldShouldReturn  calling?

Comment: Where it should be called?

Comment: i am asking that.. is this method calling? textFieldShouldReturn

Comment: Please refer below my answer... and let me know if not work..

Comment: Is your textFieldShouldReturn delegate calling after pressing return button?

Comment: @DheerajD yes it's calling I tried to print something and it's calling after pressing enter

Comment: do you have outlet connection?

Comment: I resolved that only if statement is logically error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated it according to your requirement

Try using:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textfield: UITextField!) -> Bool
{
    if (textfield == self.usernameTextField) {
        self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if (textfield == self.passwordTextField) {
        textfield.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

The `keyboard` is being dismissed due to the call to **`resignFirstResponder`**. It has nothing at all to do with the return value of **`textFieldShouldReturn`**. That's why need to write in satisfying condition.

Comment: It will not work for OP because OP is working with Swift 3 and that is the reason `textFieldShouldReturn` not getting called for OP.

Comment: what is the OP !
I tried your answer also it is not working

Comment: i don't know... :)

Comment: Have you checked connected outlet and delegate in storyboard?

Comment: @SamahAhmed Here **OP(Original Poster)** means you.

Comment: @NiravD hahahahaha :D

Comment: @DheerajD yes I can update my post with picture of that now

Comment: @DheerajD  I'm sorry you are true from the first

Comment: @DheerajD only I didn't notice from the first the first part of if statement it was going to password not to user TextField so it was my error in my logic , Thanks again :D

Comment: Wecome Samah :)

Answer (score 2):

You are working with Swift 3 and signature for method of [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/) is change so you need to pass `_` as first parameter label. So your method [`textFieldShouldReturn(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn) should be like this.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { 
    if (textfield == self.usernameTextField) {
         self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else {
         textfield.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: When else condition will execute?

Comment: Ohk.. but he has only two textfields

Comment: @SamahAhmed Have you replace your method and try my one?

Comment: @SamahAhmed You need to add `_` as first parameter label in your method like my answer, Check once again the answer properly.

Comment: @NiravD yes and give me  Use of unresolved identifier 'textfield' and when put _ textfield also not working

Comment: @SamahAhmed There is a space between `_`and `textfield` Check my answer properly. It is not `_textField`.

Comment: You must see the first part of if statement should go to password Textfield not to the username textfield and this my error from the first

Comment: @SamahAhmed That might be the issue, but you have said you are working with Swift 3 and without adding `_` as first parameter label your method will never be called. i'm 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0):

if textFieldShouldReturn is getting called, then you must write like :

```
if (textfield == self.usernameTextField) 
{
    self. passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this...

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
var usernameTextField: UITextField!
var passwordTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    usernameTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textfield: UITextField!) -> Bool
{

    if (textfield == self.usernameTextField) {
        self.usernameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    }
    else if (textfield == self.passwordTextField) {
        self.passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    return true
}
```

}